# Как воспроизвести звук в Python, параллельно с программой?

Tags: python, аудио

Я написал небольшую игру на Python, используя библиотеку PyGame. Все работает отлично, однако, вопреки выражению: "Работает - не трожь", я решил добавить фоновую музыку для игры. Вот тут и начались проблемы, я пробовал разные библиотеки для проигрывания звуков, такие как: `playsound`, `pyglet`, но везде возникала одна и та же проблема. При запуске самой игры, начинала проигрываться музыка, однако делать все игровые действия (ходить персонажем и т.д) я не мог. Я пробовал создавать отдельную функцию для воспроизведения и активировать ее в разных частях кода (в конце, в начале, середине), однако проблема оставалась.

Хотелось бы узнать, какую библиотеку можно использовать или как использовать те, которые прововал я, только чтобы я мог выполнять все действия в игре, но при этом играла музыка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно же делать звуки прямо в pygame

Включить звуковой эффект один раз

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('boom.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
```

Проигрывать постоянно по кругу (для фона)

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('foo.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Добавить следующую музыку в очередь:

```
pygame.mixer.music.queue('next_song.mp3')
```

Остановить

```
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

Comment: Попробовал, как вы сказали, звук не воспроизводится

Comment: Попробовал выбрать другой файл с музыкой, все заработало. Видимо, проблема была как раз в файле, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Давайте будем вместе читать документацию [playsound](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/). Читаем:

> It requires one argument - the path to the file with the sound you’d
>   like to play. This may be a local file, or a URL.
>
> There’s an optional second argument, block, which is set to True by
>   default. Setting it to False makes the function run asynchronously.

Первым аргументом указываем путь, вторым включаем асинхронность, но должен заметить, что такой вариант на Linux не работает.

```
playsound('play.mp3', False)
```

---

Если вариант с `pygame`:

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("play.mp3")
mixer.music.play()
input()
```

Comment: @h4cktivist обновил

Comment: в какой части кода лучше это задать? Или нет разницы?

Comment: @h4cktivist загрузить лучше вначале, вместе со всемя загрузками, запустить там где надо

Comment: Осталась та же проблема: звук есть, а играть не могу

Comment: @h4cktivist что вы имеете ввиду "играть не могу", вы убрали `input()`, я его добавил чтобы программа сама по себе не закрывалась

Comment: Да, input() я убрал. Под "играть не могу" имею ввиду то, что не могу управлять персонажем, он не реагирует на нажатия. Как бы воспроизведение музыки не дает дальше работать коду