# Собственный "браузер" для воспроизведения эфира радио на Python

Tags: python, браузер

Хочу сделать свой "Браузер", который сможет воспроизводить аудио по ссылке. Ну или что-то похожее на радио. Есть ссылка на воспроизводимый аудиофайл в прямом эфире, который можно раздобыть на сайте радио. Хочу создать приложение на Python, которое поможет мне воспроизвести этот файл в прямом эфире. Есть причина, по которым обычный браузер не справляется (жрёт ОЗУ). Помогите найти библиотеки для подобного, буду признателен

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201335/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-python/1201368#1201368

Comment: Спасибо. Правда я пишу на Python Tkinter, но я попробую что-то придумать

Comment: GreenPy тут особо думать не надо. Инсталлируйте PyQt5 и слушайте.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109158/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA-%D0%B2-python-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: Установите VLC или подобные плееры.